# Using the Iris Flower dataset, why does my classifier classify any data inputted as "Iris - Virginica"?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python

I'm a high school senior who is very new to making neural networks. I've been using the Iris Flower dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/arshid/iris-flower-dataset) to build my neural network. My model gets above 90% accuracy for both the training and the testing data, however when I made my classifier using the weights and biased terms from the model, the classifier always classifies the data as "Iris - Virginica". I am not sure what the problem is, and any help would be appreciated. It should be noted that I want to make the neural network myself using feed forward, backpropagation, gradient descent, etc. I do not want to use an existing classifier from a well-known library (e,g KNeighbors from SKLearn). My code is below.

```
#Full Code

#importing necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv") #loading the data into Python
df.head()#checking the contents to manipulate

#Preprocessing the data (making the features and the targets)

X = np.asmatrix(np.copy(df))[:,:5] #getting all the columns of the feature data
X = np.delete(X, 0, axis = 1) #dropping column of index 0 because it is "id".

nameOfTargets = df.Species.unique() #Getting the unique values of the target column for one hot encoding

Y_data = [] #Empty list that will eventually become target data
for i in df.iloc[:,5]:
    for j in range(nameOfTargets.shape[0]): #for j from 0 to N, where N is the number of items in nameOfTargets
        if i == nameOfTargets[j]:       
            Y_data.append(j)
    #The index number of the item in nameOfTargets is how they will be represented 
        #in the target data. I.E if the value of the target is equal to the FIRST 
        #item of nameOfTargets, the value is represented by the item's INDEX (0).

N = len(Y_data) #Getting the number of items in the dataset
Y = np.zeros(N*nameOfTargets.shape[0]).reshape(N,nameOfTargets.shape[0]) 
#Making the target matrix. The number of rows = number of subjects, number of columns = number of unique targets


for i in range(N): #One Hot Encoding. After the loop finishes, Y will be the final target matrix.
    t = Y_data[i]
    Y[i,t] = 1


#Standardizing values in the feature matrix X
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    X[:,i] = (X[:,i].astype(float) - np.mean(X[:,i].astype(float)))/np.std(X[:,i].astype(float))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42) #Splitting the data into testing data and training data


#Deep Learning

np.random.seed(1) #making sure the weights are the same every time the cell is rerun (still random)
N,D = X_train.shape #N = num subjects, D = num features
M = 100 #num hidden nodes of the first hidden layer
K = nameOfTargets.shape[0] #number of outputs

iteration_num = 1000 #Number of times gradient descent will be performed
a = 0.02 #learning rate

#creating the weights
W = np.random.randn(D*M).reshape(D,M)
V = np.random.randn(M*K).reshape(M,K)


#creating the biased terms
b = np.random.randn(M).reshape(1,M)
b_ones = np.ones(N).reshape(N,1)
b = np.dot(b_ones,b)

c = np.random.randn(K).reshape(1,K)
c_ones = np.ones(N).reshape(N,1)
c = np.dot(c_ones, c)

for j in range(iteration_num): #Back Propagation

    #feed forward
    z = np.dot(X_train,W) + b
    z = 1/(1 + np.exp(-z.astype(float)))
    predictions = np.exp(np.dot(z,V) + c)

    #softmax
    for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
        predictions[i,:] = predictions[i,:]/np.sum(predictions[i,:])


    #gradient descent
    dV = np.dot(z.T,(y_train - predictions)) 
    dZ = np.dot(np.dot(np.dot((y_train - predictions), V.T).T, z),(1-z.T)) #m x n matrix
    dW = np.dot(X_train.T,dZ.T) 
    db = np.dot(np.dot(np.dot((y_train - predictions), V.T).T, z), (1-z.T)).T.sum(axis = 0)
    dc = (y_train - predictions).sum(axis = 0)


    W += a*dW.astype(float) 
    V += a*dV.astype(float) 
    b += a*db.astype(float)
    c += a*dc.astype(float)

    if j%100 == 0: #Every 100 iterations, print out the cost and accuracy
        total = -np.dot(y_train.T, np.log(predictions))
        cost = total.sum()
        Accuracy = np.mean(np.round(predictions) == y_train)
        print(cost, Accuracy)


print(" ")
print("Final Cost and Accuracy of training data: ")
print(cost, Accuracy)

#Applying the model to the test data. The X_test data must be put through the softmax function and compared to y_test

#feed forward
z = np.dot(X_test,W) + b[0]
z = 1/(1 + np.exp(-z.astype(float)))
test_predictions = np.exp(np.dot(z,V) + c[0])

#softmax
for i in range(test_predictions.shape[0]):
    test_predictions[i,:] = test_predictions[i,:]/np.sum(test_predictions[i,:])

test_Acc = np.mean(np.round(test_predictions) == y_test)
test_total = -np.dot(y_test.T, np.log(test_predictions))
test_cost = total.sum()

print(" ")
print("Cost and Accuracy of testing data: ")
print(test_cost, test_Acc)

def classify(SLen, SWid, PLen, PWid):
    X = np.array([SLen, SWid, PLen, PWid]).reshape(1,-1) #Converting to 2D matrix for calculations
    z = np.dot(X,W) + b[0]
    z = 1/(1 + np.exp(-z.astype(float)))
    test_predictions = np.exp(np.dot(z,V) + c[0])

    #softmax
    for i in range(test_predictions.shape[0]):
        test_predictions[i,:] = test_predictions[i,:]/np.sum(test_predictions[i,:])

    test_predictions = np.round(test_predictions)[0] #reshaping back to 1D matrix
    j = np.where(test_predictions == 1)[0][0]

    return nameOfTargets[j]

print(classify(4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2)
```

Comment: Training and test data? Or training and CV data?

Comment: Training and test data. I imported the Iris Flower dataset, preprocessed it and then used SKLearn's train_test_split method.

Answer (score 1):

The function for the classifier does not standardize the data, which is required for the model to make predictions because standardized data was used to train it. Standardizing the input data solves the problem.